# How to update the color bar in an interactive plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

The following code plots a 2D array, whose value can be changed interactively. The only thing missing is that I would like it to change the colobar. Somehow, when I modify the image, the colorbar doesn't adjust itself.

```
from pyplot import *
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

ax = subplot(111)
subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

my_img=random((100,100))*10.

l = imshow(my_img,origin='lower');cbar=colorbar()

ax1= axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='w')

par1 = Slider(ax1, 'normalization', 1, 100., valinit=1.5)

def update(val):
  new_normalization = par1.val
  new_img=random((100,100))*new_normalization

  l.set_array(new_img)

  # this doesn't change the new colobar maximum
  cbar.vmax=new_img.max()
  cbar.vmin=0
  draw()

par1.on_changed(update)

resetax = axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color='w', hovercolor='0.975')
def reset(event):
     par1.reset()

button.on_clicked(reset)
show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution myself.

All it takes is just

```
     l.set_clim([new_img.min(), new_img.max()])
```